# jQuery UI Slider - max value (not end of slider)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-slider

I have a stepped slider, with non-linear steps -

code:

```
$(function() {
    var trueValues = [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 150];
    var values =     [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 100];
    var slider = $("#parkSlider").slider({
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        range: "min",
    value: 40,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            var includeLeft = event.keyCode != $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT;
            var includeRight = event.keyCode != $.ui.keyCode.LEFT;
            var value = findNearest(includeLeft, includeRight, ui.value);
            slider.slider('value', value);
        $("#amount").val(getRealValue(value)); 
            return false;
        },

    });
    function findNearest(includeLeft, includeRight, value) {
        var nearest = null;
        var diff = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if ((includeLeft && values[i] <= value) || (includeRight && values[i] >= value)) {
                var newDiff = Math.abs(value - values[i]);
                if (diff == null || newDiff < diff) {
                    nearest = values[i];
                    diff = newDiff;
                }
            }
        }
        return nearest;
    }
    function getRealValue(sliderValue) {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] >= sliderValue) {
                return trueValues[i];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Here's my slider graphic:

[image: slider]

I have the minimum value set to be at the 5 in the graphic, but I am trying to set the max (value & position) to stop at the 150 in the graphic. No matter what I've tried, the slider goes to the full end of the slider, and I always want it to stop short at the 150.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your `values` and `trueValues` arrays and how you're handling them in the `getRealValue()` function. You're overriding the slider defaults with the `trueValues` array.

I'm a little unclear as to why you want both `values` and `trueValues`. My interpretation of your code is that `trueValues` is what the slider's default values settings are, and `values` are some sort of user-defined values.

What you want to do is `.concat()` `values` and `trueValues` into a single array and use that new array for the slider values. You should keep `range: 'min'` and perhaps set `max: 160` and `min: -5` to make the slider render nicely.

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBzqL/4/).

Comment: 'values[values.length - 1]' was removed from my question (I added that in, when I was adding in extra values to try and set the max at the position -1. My range is a fixed range for styling purposes only (the color change)

Comment: So what I am trying to do, is have a max incremental value (not the actual max value of the slider. Setting the max is easy, but I need the slider handle to stop short of the end of slider at stop at the 150 mark...

Comment: @Jason If you read both the linked and copied documentation, it will stop short at the 150 mark if you specify `range: true`.

Comment: but you can see that I only have one handle - not two. Having the range set at true, also messes with the rest of the functionality (in that it doesn't slide, as I'm setting the increments non-linear) - Also, you need to read the rest of the question - I am able to set the max value, but I need to set a max position of the slider handle at the 150 mark - I downvoted due to you not reading the full extent of the question.

Comment: You want to set `range: max`, in that case.

Comment: right, but that also sets the very end of the slider as the 150 value. I need to set it to be offset from the end as evidenced by my graphic

Comment: It would help *immensely* if you could post a jsFiddle of this with your CSS. Right now I'm playing with a jsFiddle and it's difficult to reproduce.

Comment: I will get that done later, I meant to do it this AM, but ran out of time

Comment: @Jason I think I've figured out what you want, so I'm updating my answer accordingly. Let me know if this still completely off.

Comment: AH ha! a perfect simple answer. I didn't think to set the max value a hair higher than what I wanted the final value to be. Thanks for that. On a sidenote, the reason I have the values & true values is so that I can set the increments non-linear (meaning unequal step sizes), but I still want to return the values from trueValues.